# Pausing/Queuing Actions/Events/Delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action

I need the ability to pause event/delegates.

The use-case is => There is a server that will be returning information, but I need to pause automatically updating UI elements from updating, and then release it later after they've animated.

The initial desire was to have a class or wrapper and encapsulates events/actions/delegates.

My question is...

Is there existing functionality for doing this, or a better way of approaching this problem.

Comment: You need to remove and then add again. There is no "pause" flag, as I know. But you can use a boolean conditional variable that you check at the start of an event handler if it matches the purpose: `if (isMyEventHandlerSuspended) return;`. You set it to true somewhere to "pause" and false to re-enable. But the method will be called, so if performance isn't an issue that's fine. I use that regularly mainly to avoid collisions and for example to avoid exceptions on not ready forms, but it can be used to do a "pseudo-pause".

Comment: ty i will give this a try